# For Loop not moving on when copying a range in same sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a dynamic range that I want to copy in the same worksheet, a certain amount of times depending on the value in a cell

I've tried changing how the for loop works, I've tried adding lastrow ++ but nothing seems to be working. I can't see anything wrong with the code, but there must be something!

```
function workingDays()

{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var Sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Workzone Planning');
    var sessionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Daily Plan');
    var workDays = Sheet.getRange(4, 6, 7);
    var working = Sheet.getRange('F11').getValue()
    var startRow = workDays.getRow();

    Logger.log(working)

    for (var a = 0; a < working; a++);


    var lastRow = sessionSheet.getLastRow();
    var lastCol = sessionSheet.getLastColumn();
    var startCopy = lastRow - 17

    var array = sessionSheet.getRange(startCopy, 1, 17, lastCol).activate()

    sessionSheet.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, 6)

    var currentCell = sessionSheet.getRange(lastRow + 6, 1)
    sessionSheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(currentCell)

}
```

At the moment the cell referred to in F11 is showing 6 so I would expect it to copy the range 6 times ( I actually only want it to copy 5 times, but can sort that after). What its actually doing is only copying it once (though I think it is possibly copying 6 times, but not moving on, so just copying over the top each time)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is but this line `for (var a = 0; a < working; a++);` is equivalent to `var a = working`. The `for` loop doesn't actually do any work.

Comment: looks like you are missing {} around the operations you wish to repeat... and it seems like you want to repeat all of the commands after the `for` statement

Comment: Putting a semicolon after the for loop is a problem `for (var a = 0; a < working; a++);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the statements after the for loop to execute X amount of times you need to wrap those lines in curly braces {}, otherwise the for loop executes X amount of times without doing anything other than incrementing local variable `a` and then running the subsequent statement only once.

ex:

```
for (var a = 0; a < working; a++) {
  var lastRow = sessionSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sessionSheet.getLastColumn();
  var startCopy = lastRow - 17

  var array = sessionSheet.getRange(startCopy, 1, 17, lastCol).activate()

  sessionSheet.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, 6)

  var currentCell = sessionSheet.getRange(lastRow + 6, 1)
  sessionSheet.getActiveRange().copyTo(currentCell)
}
```

Comment: Ah. I had the curly brackets there and took them out.. Will add them back in. Thank you

Comment: It was having the ; after the for statement and not having the {} around the thing I wanted to repeat that was the problem, so Zweih was spot on with his response. Thank you